# Why are the files from the contentFiles folder not getting copied over to the bin folder?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm trying to get my sql files from the nuget package to the bin folder of my Application. I was setting up the .nuspec file for it. I can see in the .nuget folder that the sql files are a part of the nuget package but they are not reflected in the bin/Debug folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Athi</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>Logger</tags>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Dapper" version="2.0.123" />
        <dependency id="System.Data.SqlClient" version="4.8.3" />
    </dependencies>
      <contentFiles>
          <files include="bin\Release\net6.0\Scripts\*.sql" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" />
      </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
      <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\Scripts\*.*" target="lib\net6.0\Scripts" />
      <file src="bin\Release\net6.0\Scripts\*.*" target="contentFiles\Scripts" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Are you sure `bin\Release\net6.0\Scripts` is the right path?

Comment: @shingo I can see the files in the .nuget folder. Doesn't that mean that they were picked up when generating the nuget?

Comment: In the .nuget folder? Can you show the structure of your nupkg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#package-folder-structure):

> The package project should structure content using the following pattern:

```
/contentFiles/{codeLanguage}/{TxM}/{any?}
```

> For example:

```
Language- and framework-agnostic:
    /contentFiles/any/any/config.xml

net45 content for all languages
    /contentFiles/any/net45/config.xml

C#-specific content for net45 and up
    /contentFiles/cs/net45/sample.cs
```

It doesn't look like you are putting them into the correct directory in your NuGet package.

Secondly, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files), `contentFiles` is only supported on `NuGet 4.0+ with PackageReference`. Are you using a high enough version of NuGet? Are you using `PackageReference` in your project files instead of a `packages.config` file in your project?

> **TIP:** If you find the documentation is lacking in examples of what you are attempting to do, download some (recently made) real packages from https://nuget.org to locate one that does something similar to what you want and use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://dotnetfoundation.org/projects/nuget-package-explorer) to see how the packages are arranged.